# Can't compile Java 13 and Groovy 2.5.8

Tags: java, groovy, compiler-errors, java-13

I have a project (Spring Boot application), in which I mix Java and Groovy.

I can compile and run the project without problems inside IntelliJ Idea.

But I can't compile it with Maven.

Java 12 works fine, but when switching to 13 version it shows me next errors:

[image: error trace image]

Example of POM.xml configuration:

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>

    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>

    <javax.version>1.5.4</javax.version>

    <groovy.version>2.5.8</groovy.version>

    <lombok.version>1.18.10</lombok.version>

....

 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
          <source>{java.version}</source>
          <target>{java.version}</target>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <compilerArguments>
            <javaAgentClass>lombok.launch.Agent</javaAgentClass>
          </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0-03</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}-01</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Does anyone know which compiler/plugin compiles java and groovy code with the java 13 version?

Comment: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/963 which is tagged as the 3.6.0 release (looks like all work for that finished at the start of this year, but no release as yet)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots.  Paste the relevant text parts in the question so they can be searched and copied.

Answer (score 0):

Java 13 support starts in groovy-eclipse-batch 2.5.8-03, which is based upon Eclipse 4.14. https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/jdt.php#Java_13

You are using 2.5.8-01. At this time, Groovy 2.5.10 is the latest release and groovy-eclipse-batch:2.5.10-01 matches that. And both offer support for Java 13.